# how to convert number to 4 decimals place in V.B

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I am trying to make number appear in to 4 decimal places, this code I typed, it only dislay a number into 2 decimal places

```
 Private Sub btnAverage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAverage.Click
    Dim dnumber1 As Decimal = txtNum1.Text
    lblNumber.Text = FormatNumber(dnumber1)

End Sub
```

Comment: what's `FormatNumber`?

Comment: @Hasan Have you even bothered looking up the [documentation for `FormatNumber()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.90).aspx)? You would have seen that the number of decimal places is the first optional parameter.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Do you mean the     Function Strings
if that, it didn't say anything about places of decimals but if your talking about something else then no I didn't see that.
If you tell me tat would be very hrlpful

Comment: In order to make it easy to succeed. MS/VS puts all sorts of information like that at your fingertips - or rather mouse cursor. Dont ignore the pop up Intellisense as you try to type code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs for FormatNumber - the second argument is the number of digits after the decimal point.

```
lblNumber.Text = FormatNumber(dnumber1,4)
```